# Sending an e-mail with an image inline that is attached comes up as ATT00001 on some computers

Tags: c#, email, smtp, email-attachments

This is working fine locally but when I sent it to another person in the company (same exchange server) using Outlook on a mac, it does not work correctly. Instead, the image is replaced with the text ATT00001 and the image becomes an attachment called ATT0001

It was tricky to get this working in the first place, here is the code I use:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("EmailManager.Kitten.jpg");

var inlineLogo = new LinkedResource(stream, "image/jpg");
inlineLogo.ContentId = "CompanyLogo";

body = body.Replace("{logourl}", string.Format("cid:{0}", inlineLogo.ContentId));

var view = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
view.LinkedResources.Add(inlineLogo);

mailMessage.Body = body;
mailMessage.Subject = "Check out the kitty logo";
mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(view);
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(....);

smtp.Send(mailMessage);
```

The body is just a string of stuff with an `<img src='{logourl}' />` in it.

Any suggestions of what I might do to fix or debug this? Alternatively is there a way to link to an external image without outlook blocking it by default (eg. having it come from the same server or similar).

Edit: I've read something about macs wanting the attachments listing at the end of the e-mail, could this be it? Although there is no way I can see from the above how to specify this behaviour. Also I am not entirely sure it's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**can be one of the possible solution**

> > i have found answer .bin file comes when `_EmailLogo1` and
> >     `_EmailLogo` are empty so need to check if it's empty/NULL or not !! if not empty/NULL then it should be linked otherwise don't !!

```
dynamic htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(_Body.ToString(), null, "text/html");
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_EmailLogo1)) {
    LinkedResource logo = new LinkedResource(_EmailLogo);
    logo.ContentId = "logo2";
    htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(logo);
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_EmailLogo))
{
LinkedResource logo1 = new LinkedResource(_EmailLogo1);
logo1.ContentId = "logo1";
htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(logo1);
aMessage.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some email clients are smart enough to display correctly whereas others require you to be very specific with your AlternateView and LinkedResource. Have you tried with other email clients e.g. Windows Live Mail?

Try specifying the ContentType of your AlternateView:

`view.ContentType = new ContentType("text/html");`

I had the same issue where Outlook did the same, displayed the image as an unnamed attachment however Windows Live Mail worked perfectly.

Fast forward to when we moved our SMTP server to Mandrill and we hit the same issue for all email clients where emails displayed as unnamed attachments and it turned out we didn't specify one of our ContentType's and it defaulted to "application/octet-stream"

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is a bit old, but I have noticed that some issues occur when you use ' instead of " wrapping the source. 
Try instead to write it like this `<img src="{logourl}" />`
Hope this helps someone.