# inline image is coming as .bin file while sending email Outlook 2016

Tags: outlook, smtp, html-email, email-attachments, inline-images

> i am trying to send Inline image in html and it is coming as .bin file
>
> i have already read the answer of this Quesstion

[Sending an e-mail with an image inline that is attached comes up as ATT00001 on some computers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256856/sending-an-e-mail-with-an-image-inline-that-is-attached-comes-up-as-att00001-on)
**but still not able to solve it**

```
string DexuslogoImage2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Images\\DexusTenantNotice.png");
string strBody = strBody.Replace("##DexusNoticeLogo##", "cid:Dexuslogo1");

dynamic htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(_Body.ToString(), null, "text/html");
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_EmailLogo)) {
    LinkedResource logo = new LinkedResource(_EmailLogo);
    logo.ContentId = "Dexuslogo1";
    htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(logo);
}

LinkedResource logo1 = new LinkedResource(_EmailLogo1);
logo1.ContentId = "Dexuslogo2";

htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(logo1);
aMessage.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
```

Comment: you should have commented on the earlier question to see if the OP had found an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> i have found answer .bin file comes when `_EmailLogo1` and `_EmailLogo` are empty so need
>   to check if it's empty or not !!

```
dynamic htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(_Body.ToString(), null, "text/html");
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_EmailLogo1)) {
    LinkedResource logo = new LinkedResource(_EmailLogo);
    logo.ContentId = "Dexuslogo2";
    htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(logo);
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_EmailLogo))
{
LinkedResource logo1 = new LinkedResource(_EmailLogo1);
logo1.ContentId = "Dexuslogo2";
htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(logo1);
aMessage.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
}
```